# How to enable clean URL?

Tags: server, url, drupal

I've a little problem with my drupal installation, because I need to enable clean URL but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion? 
*I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. My problem was that my .htaccess file was called .htacces, without the final S.